# Calculus question about the existence of antiderivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be the function equal $0$ on $\mathbb R_{<0}$ and equal $1$ otherwise. Is clear to me that $f$ has derivative undefined at $x=0$. Is intuitive because the derivative would be $\infty$ as $f$ increases by $1$ in an infinitely small space.

Now I was wondering whether antiderivative exists at $0$. My thoughts: antiderivative corresponds to area under the function. Before zero the are is always zero and after zero the area is $1$ so that like in derivative case the area increases by $1$ in an infinitely small space. But I don't know if intuition can be used in this case.

When does antiderivatives of functions exists in general and when not?

Comment: For one thing, f is not continuous at 0, so it cannot be differentiable there, since differentiability implies continuity.

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative#Uses_and_properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two correct answers so far invoke the intermediate value property of derivatives, so I thought it might be useful to give an alternative argument avoiding that fact. Notice first that your function $f$ is (Riemann) integrable over any finite interval.  In particular, its integral from $-1$ to $x$ is $0$ for $x\leq0$ and $x$ for $x\geq0$.  If $f$ had an antiderivative $F$, then, by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $F$ would have to agree with this integral, up to an additive constant of integration.  That is, there would be a constant $C$ such that $F(x)$ equals $C$ for $x\leq0$ and equals $x+C$ for $x\geq0$.  But then the derivative of $F$ at zero doesn't exist, so $F$ can't be the antiderivative of anything.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I think Riemann integrability of $f$ suffices, but I confess that, when I try to prove it, I find myself using the mean value theorem, which makes this as hard as the Darboux theorem. But even if one requires continuity of $f$, my argument could be used to show that $F$ has the claimed form on each half of $\mathbb R$, and no such $F$ is differentiable at $0$. (I don't even need that the constant $C$ is the same on both sides.)

Comment: I agree; thinking of it in terms of the two one-sided cases seems to be the simplest solution.

Comment: Upon further reflection: indeed I was not using the right version of FTC.  The one we need is Theorem 8.15 of http://math.uga.edu/~pete/2400full.pdf.  (And you're exactly right: the proof uses the Mean Value Theorem.  So for this application we might as well just prove Darboux's Theorem, it seems to me too.)  Sorry, I wasn't really on top of this one...

Comment: Andreas Blass: Wouldn't $C=0$ be okay? Then $F$ would be continuous, $0$ for $x \le 0$ and $x$ for $x \ge 0$.

Comment: @blue: $F$ would be continuous but not differentiable at 0, so, as I said, it can't be the antiderivative of anything.

Answer (score 3):

For such function does not exist any antiderivative; that is because even if $F$ is derivable with derivative discontinuous $F'$ always respect the intermediate value property, so assuming $0$ and $1$ and never $\frac{1}{2}$, $f$ is not a derivative of any function.

What exists is its definite integral, in any derivable point of this integral the derivative is the value of $f$ but such integral is not derivable in $0$ only continuous.

Comment: I disagree -- f certainly has an antiderivative for the entire real line.  See below.

Answer (score 3):

To be sure, the assertion that for any differentiable function $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, the derivative $f': I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has the intermediate value property (whether it is continuous or not!) is a theorem of J.G. Darboux.  For a careful statement and proof, see e.g. Theorem 5.30 [of these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/2400full.pdf), or [consult wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29).

The basic idea is simple: one can reduce to the case in which $a< b \in I$, $f'(a) < 0$, $f'(b) > 0$, and one wants to show that there is a $c$ with $a < c < b$ such that $f'(c) = 0$.  In fact the conditions $f'(a) < 0$ and $f'(b) > 0$ imply that the function $f$ cannot have a minimum value at either $a$ or $b$.  Since $f$ is differentiable, $f$ is continuous and takes a minimum somewhere on $[a,b]$, hence necesssarily at an interior point $c$, and then we must have $f'(c) = 0$.

Comment: But in my example $f'$ is never $<0$? How to apply this argument here?

Comment: @blue: I'm just proving Darboux's Theorem.  By "one can reduce to", I mean that one checks that one can change the function slightly so as to make these conditions true in such a way that proving the result for the changed function implies the result for the original function (much as in the proof of the Intermediate Value Theorem).  All this is described in my notes that I linked to...

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.

Answer (score -1):

Due to the extensive and off point discussion that followed my original answer, I want to clarify what I meant and why I see things that way.  I hope you will find this helpful and to the point.

First, if you are student, and your book defines an antiderivative of f on [a,b] as a function F for which F'(x) = f(x) on [a,b] (this is a little wrong re the endpoints, but we could fuss our way around that); and if your teacher agrees with your book; then you should do it their way until you get your A in the course.

However, this is not the only way to do things.  The main reason for defining the antiderivative in this way is so that the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus can be stated as:

$\int_a^bf(x)$ dx = F(b) - F(a) where F is the antiderivative of f on [a,b].

Given the above definition of antiderivative this is true and correct.  But is is unnecessary.  We can state the Fundamental Theorem as

If F(x) is a function such that F'(x) = f(x) for all x $\in$ (a,b) and F is continuous at a and b then

(1)...  $\int_a^bf(x)$ dx = F(b) - F(a)

(which is how I learned it). Note the word "antiderivative" does not appear.  Many mathematicians use this way of stating the theorem, and you can find it in Apostol's Real Analysis.  In over 500 pages, this truly excellent book does not anywhere use the term "antiderivative".

Having severed the term "antiderivative" from the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, we are free to define it less restrictively, and in a way that may be more useful.

Under the restrictive definition a piecewise continuous function on (a,b), say g, such as in the original question, cannot have an antiderivative on the entire (a,b).  This can give the mistaken impression that g may not be integrable on [a,b], when nothing could be farther from the truth. It also gives rise to the kind of confusion the original question raises, as to a simple, well-behaved function not having an antiderivative.

With the restriction removed, however, we can let F(x) be a continuous function on all of [a,b] whose derivative matches f where it exists.  Integration would proceed piecewise as implied by (1). Or we could use the term any other way that is useful.  Or not use it at all as per Apostol.

Because I never was subject to the more restrictive definition, I have always used the term "antiderivative" rather vaguely to mean something you can differentiate to get f.  I use it this way as a shortcut in my thinking, so I can proceed in a problem without getting bogged down in details. The details must, of course, be handled eventually, but that would be in the final write up of the problem.

Finally a word about definitions.  Some are so embedded in mathematics that they cannot be easily changed, and so useful we wouldn't want to.  And we don't want too much flexibility because then no one would understand what anyone else was talking about.  So a Riemann integral, a group, n! etc. all have definitions everyone agrees about.

However, there are definitions which are not in universal use.  The mathematics doesn't change, but the way people talk about it does.  It also often happens that an original definition which is in widespread use turns out to be too restrictive.  An example would be the original definition of "eigenvalue".  After awhile there was a new definition: generalized eigenvalue -- because it was needed.

All this is a way of saying that just because something is written down in a book doesn't mean it is the best way to do things, or even that it is true. If you are taking a course you have to get your grade.  If you are trying to do mathematics you have to think for yourself.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, a more permissive definition of an antiderivative of an (integrable) function $f$ was given by Lebesgue: $F$ is absolutely continuous and $F' = f$ almost everywhere.  One gets an extension of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.  According to this definition the OP's given $f$ does have an antiderivative.  It must be understood that any answer of "yes" or "no" is relative to a particular context and setup (and thus that context must be properly understood in order to answer the question), and that in a different context the answer may change.

Answer (score -3):

The function F(x) = 0 for x < 0, F(x) = x for x ≥ 0 is an antiderivative for the function f that you describe.  Or if you prefer F(x) = c for x < 0 and F(x) = x + c for x ≥ 0, where c is any real number. Notice that F(x) is continuous on the entire real line, but not differentiable at x = 0 (which is as it should be).

Any piecewise continuous function on the interval (a,b) will have an antiderivative there, and most of the functions you are likely to run into will be at least piecewise continuous.  To avoid having an antiderivative, the function has to avoid being piecewise continuous, which is very discontinuous indeed, but can happen.  For example, the function g(x) = 0 where x is rational and 1 where x is irrational does not have an antiderivative on the interval (a,b).

In general integration is much more forgiving than differentiation.  That is because addition is additive, in fact is really an average, which tends to smooth things out. (That's why people use 4 week running averages to analyze trends-- they are smoother than the underlying daily data.)

Whereas, the existence of a f'(c)  (c any number) implies that f is locally linear in the neighborhood of c.  That is, f and the tangent line to f at c are very similar in a small enough interval of c.  Obviously a function with a discontinuity cannot be locally linear at that point, nor can a function like |x| (at zero).

Comment: The standard definition of an **antiderivative** of a function $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function $F: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $F'(x) = x$ for all $x \in I$.  Thus antiderivatives need to be everywhere differentiable by definition.  If you want to explore a nonstandard definition, please at least include that definition.

Comment: Also: is "locally linear" anything other than a synonym for "differentiable"?  I.e., does it have an independent meaning?  And I would say that differentiable functions are continuous is intuitively plausible and easy to prove from the definition of the derivative but not "obvious".

Comment: Locally linear is indeed a synonym for differentiable, and one that is greatly underused. I don't think I said it is "obvious" that differentiable functions are continuous, although as you say, easy enough to prove. Re your standard definition, strangely I've never seen it and always admitted piecewise antiderivatives.  Since they exist mainly to help evaluate integrals, it isn't clear to me why we should insist that they are everywhere differentiable.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that there are some functions which are everywhere differentiable on a given interval but are very difficult to work with and lead to nasty, unintuitive results.  A piecewise differentiable function resulting from a finite number of jumps in f is quite tame and very helpful. So yeah, I would prefer admitting them to the club. You probably don't have to tweak the standard definition much to allow that.

Comment: $@$Betty: You wrote "Obviously a function with a discontinuity cannot be locally linear at that point".  If locally linear is really fully synonymous with "differentiable", what is the advantage in using the term?

Comment: You have a PhD in applied mathematics, so it is very hard for me to believe that you haven't encountered the standard definition of the derivative.  But you do need to be aware of standard definitions when answering undergraduate level questions.  If you want to discuss a nonstandard definition, you need to be explicit about this and in particular give the alternate definition, which you still haven't quite done.  (Also: clearly functions which are everywhere differentiable are no nastier than functions which are piecewise differentiable, so I don't understand your motivation.)

Comment: I presume you mean standard definition of the antiderivative. As for never seeing it presented that way, you'd be amazed at what gets left out over the years, and I had no reason to ask questions about that; although I am a questioner.  I think the definition you give, while certainly clear, is rather restrictive in view the purpose of the antiderivative and could be generalized to everyone's advantage.

Comment: Look at the function x^2sin(1/x) x not 0; 0 when x = 0.  It is differentiable at 0, with a discontinuous derivative.  Discontinuous derivatives of this kind tend to be useful mostly for upsetting everyone's notions of what derivatives are and how they work; whereas a function that simply lacks a derivative at a point can be handled easily by breaking up the interval. Re antiderivatives perhaps this:Use your mapping terminology and then say F(x) is continuous everywhere and differentiable except at a finite number of points; where differentiable F'(x) = f(x).

Comment: Re Locally linear; there are plenty of continuous functions like |x| that are not locally linear at some point. Locally linear at a means that in some neighborho0d of a f(x) = f(a) + f'(x-a) + R(x) where R(x)/(x-a) goes to 0 as x goes to a.  This is an alternate definition of the derivative but really useful for proving various things (try L'Hospital's rule), and also for illuminating why they are true (i.e. they are true for linear functions, and if the function is close to linear they are still true).

Comment: yes, I should have said "antiderivative" in my comment.  As for generalizing the definition: there are hundreds of generalizations of derivative and antiderivative in various contexts (almost everywhere differentiable, approximately differentiable,...).  But when you answer student questions at the level of freshman calculus, you need to be familiar with the standard definition.  If you want to discuss an alternate definition, please **say so and give that definition**.

Comment: Regarding your example: if you change $x^2 \sin (\frac{1}{x})$ to $x \sin (\frac{1}{x})$ then the function is not differentiable at $0$.  How do you propose to "handle this easily" by breaking up the interval?

Comment: Regarding "locally linear": your proposed definition does not make sense: move $f(a)$ to the left, divide by $x-a$, and take limits as $x \rightarrow a$ to get $f'(a) = \lim_{x \rightarrow a} f'(x-a)/(x-a)$.  This does not hold in general.  Were you perhaps thinking of Carathedory's differentiability criterion: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_Theorem_%28Analysis%29?

Comment: Yes, I typed it wrong.  It should have said f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + R(x), where R still has the property I mentioned. Sorry.

Comment: I brought up the example of x^2sin(1/x) as an example of a function which is everywhere differentiable and not as nice as a piecewise differentiable function.  It is certainly true that xsin(1/x) is not differentiable at 0, but what is the connection with our discussion?

Comment: $@$Betty: The function I gave seems to be a counterexample to your claim "whereas a function that simply lacks a derivative at a point can be handled easily by breaking up the interval".

Comment: Also: I am not fan of the term "locally linear" (it is not compatible with terminology *locally X* in general topology), but now that I know that by that term you mean what you said (which is essentially Caratheodory's criterion; it is also the $n = 1$ case of "Taylor's Theorem Without Remainder"): sure, that is a useful formulation of differentiability.

Comment: Peter, I think you have not said, but should have that without the differentiability requirement for an antiderivative the handy little formula F(b)-F(a) will not give a corrrect value for the definite integral. I have concerns about approaching it this way, altho it's standard in 1st year calc classes. One is that "doesn't have an antiderivative" sounds like (altho it doesn't imply) that the function is not integrable.  Another that it is anti-intuitive for exactly the kind of situation that was presented.  continued

Comment: 3rd, that it makes it easy for kids to slap a formula in place instead of thinking about what they are doing.  The theory can be completely developed without the derivative requirement on F generally (tho it has to be there for the F(b)-F(a) to work in a given interval).  Re xsin1/x it is a differentiable on any interval that omits 0.  So if you have an interval that spans 0, you can break it up into left of 0 and right of 0.  Yes,re Taylor's theorem altho we use a remainder, just don't specify it; and also yes that it is an alternate def of derivative.

Comment: Locally linear means to me that the function is nearly linear in some neighborhood of the point (sorry about the general topology conflict); thus something that is true for a linear function may well be true for a differentiable function; this provides a general approach to tackling a class of proofs and automatically illuminates why things are true.  The Taylor's connection is a plus -- it shows where things might go if there are further derivatives; it also connects the Taylor's devlopment to the original definition of derivative.

Comment: "Peter, I think you have not said, but should have that without the differentiability requirement for an antiderivative" Betty, you still seem not to have grasped that the **definition** of "$F$ is an antiderivative of $f$" is $F' = f$.  If you want to write a book / teach classes / whatever using an alternate definition, you are free to do so, but your desire that this not be the standard definition in all contemporary calculus texts does not make it so.

Comment: About "antiderivative" versus "integrable": yes, there are two different and not fully compatible things coming under the name "integral".  Having students not think that the definition of $\int_a^b f$ is $F(b)-F(a)$ where $F' = f$ is one of the challenges of teaching this material.  But one of the ways to help with this is not to use "definite integral" versus "indefinite integral" but rather a different noun, **antiderivative**, for the latter.  If you want to see how these terminological issues are approached, you can consult any calculus text, of which many are freely available online.

Comment: One of them (which is at a more advanced and theoretical level) is available here: http://math.uga.edu/~pete/2400full.pdf....I didn't realize that by "breaking up" an interval you meant simply avoiding the point of nondifferentiability; I thought you meant splitting up the interval into two halfintervals and looking at one-sided derivatives, which was my understanding of your alternate definition of antiderivative.  But okay, how about Weierstrass's nowhere differentiable continuous function: what will you do with that in terms of piecewise differentiability?

Comment: My point is that "nearly linear in some neighborhood of the point" doesn't mean anything more or less than "differentiable at that point".  With regard to Taylor's Theorem: there are two versions of Taylor's Theorem.  The one "without remainder" is discussed in $\S$ 12.2 of the notes linked to above.  The one "with remainder" is discussed in $\S$ 12.3 of the notes linked to above.

Comment: "The theory can be completely developed without the derivative requirement on F generally" Please state the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for your alternate version of the antiderivative.  (To be less passive-aggressive about it: this is not possible.)  If you mean that some discontinuous functions are integrable: yes, of course: I know the (Riemann-)Lebesgue Theorem and I hope you do too.  But being integrable and having an antiderivative are distinct concepts.

Comment: Finally, "Locally linear means to me that the function is nearly linear in some neighborhood of the point" Unfortunately that doesn't quite work.  Unless the function is actually linear on some neighborhood of the point (a trivial case), you can't mean that $f$ is close to being linear on any fixed interval: you must mean something more subtle about the approximation to linearity getting arbitrarily good as the length of the interval approaches $0$: i.e., differentiability at the point.

Comment: Peter, Weierstrass's nowhere differentiable continuous function is not the antiderivative of anything by anyone's definition. Re linearity, nearly linear in some neighborhood can be expanded as 'you decide how near "nearly" is and there will be neighborhood in which the function meets that requirement.  That is equivalent to the statement that R(x)/(x-a) goes to zero as x goes to a.  As for standard calculus books, I have many problems with the ten or so I've looked at, including serious outright errors, confusing presentations, and serious failure to distinguish what is important and say why.

Comment: Every time I teach a class I wind up writing extensive notes of my own, and hardly refer to the book at all.

Comment: Why are you calling me "Peter"?  Please don't.  What you say about Weierstrass's function is not necessarily true, but that would be getting very far off-topic.  You have been making claims that piecewise differentiable functions are a better class of functions than differentiable functions.  This doesn't make much sense to me, but in the absence of a precise definition and claim on your part it is probably not worth discussing.  If you don't mind my asking, I'm curious: have you actually taught calculus at a university?  Recently?

Comment: Regarding standard calculus books: they are not very inspiring, I agree, but it is rare for them to have outright errors.  Part of teaching calculus is learning the terminology and notation that others are using.  For perhaps the fifth time, it is fine if you want to present your own definition of antiderivative: I've invited you to do so several times, and you haven't edited your answer at all.  What is not acceptable is acting, either through ignorance or pretense, as though the standard definition does not exist: this is a disservice to students and disrespectful to teachers.

Comment: Hey Peter, I did indeed provide you an alternate definition.  Read again.  Re calculus books not having outright errors, surely you jest.

Comment: I have asked you to edit your **answer**, which you have not done.  Further, your failure to address me in the way I have asked (i.e., by my username, which is also my professional name) makes me unwilling to have further correspondence with you.